# Specifying range for Opensolver in vba

Tags: excel, solver, vba

I’ve set different ranges like so:

```
rA3 = Sheets("Testa").Range("V1")
rB3 = Sheets("Testa").Range("W1")
rA4 = Sheets("Testa").Range("I2:K200")
sAdjust = Sheets("Testa").Range("F2:K200")
OpenSolver.AddConstraint LHSRange:=rA3, Relation:=RelationGE, RHSRange:=rB3
```

From what I see, these don't seem to be recognized by `OpenSolver.SetObjectiveFunctionCell` or `OpenSolver.AddConstraint`, you have to add them using `Cells(i,j)` and `Union`. 
Whenever I try to compile the code I get the following error

> Erreur de compilation Type d'arguments ByRef incompatible

which loosely translated means that the `ByRef` argument is incompatible.

Does anyone know how I can add big ranges like `sAdjust` efficiently?

Comment: Maybe it is because of the commas that I see in your original question? (`“Testa”`). Notice, that in the edited version there are the correct commas (`"Testa"`). In the original [OpenSolver help page](https://opensolver.org/help/comment-page-38/), I see the wrong commas too, which may cause problems, if pasted like that...

Comment: You will need to explain what "*how I can add big ranges like sAdjust efficiently?*" means. That's too less information. Do you get any errors? What is your issue?

Comment: I'll edit the first post with more information. The commas are correct in vba, when I copied they got distorted.

Comment: Try `Set`, because that is how `Range` objects are supposed to be created. E. g., `Set rA3 = Sheets("Testa").Range("V1")`

Comment: @Doule just make you use `Option Explicit` then it tells you if your quotes are correct or not! Wrong quotes are considered as variable an throw a variable not defined error.

Comment: Did both those things and I got rid of the error ! Thanks.